# Max file size that can be uploaded in VSTS testcase results attachment

Tags: azure-devops

What is the max file size that I can upload via python script to testcase result attachments?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the maximum total size of attachment allowed to be uploaded to test result is **100MB**.

[image]

Comment: how to increase this setting on azure devops?